# gsub required for character + using R

Tags: r, replace, gsub

I'm new to R. I'm stucked on some step for my project. I'm  unable to `gsub`  character `+` 
For example if i  have string like `KHJVG+56A` the result should be `KHJVG56A`.

Here is what I'm trying.

```
gsub('^+[[:punct]]', "", 'KHJVG+56A')
```

But am getting same string which  I passed

Comment: `gsub("\\+","",'KHJVG+56A')`

Comment: Thanks @nicola. You saved my time

Comment: Now  what should I do if i  want to replace  wholeword 'KHJVG+56A'

Comment: Which word would you like to replace?

Comment: See if want to replace the word 'KHJVG+56A' to ADFGVJ USING GSUB since the presence of + i cannot directly replace

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your problem?

```
gsub('[[:punct:]]', "", 'KHJVG+56A')
```

I think you don't really need the `^` (beginning of line) and one `:` was missing.

As stated by @nicola, `gsub('\\+', "", 'KHJVG+56A')` is even more specific to `+`, where `[[:punct:]] would target any punctuation sign.

Comment: See if want to replace the word 'KHJVG+56A' to ADFGVJ USING GSUB since the presence of + i cannot directly replace

Comment: I don't understand how this is related to your initial question